# Get the Action Value of APIKit Router Mapping in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-esb, apikit

Say this is my router config

```
<apikit:config name="apiConfig" raml="api.raml" doc:name="Router" >
   <apikit:flow-mapping resource="/resourceOne" action="get" flow-ref="flow-1"/>
   <apikit:flow-mapping resource="/resourceTwo" action="post" flow-ref="flow-1"/>
</apikit:config>
```

As you can see the calls to these two resources are being redirected to the same flow, but based on the method action.

How do I read this action value (Get or Post) in the called flow `flow-1`?

Comment: Why are you mapping flows manually instead of using auto generated flows which is the default and recommended mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be having separate flows, but if you need to it this way, you can use `#[attributes.method]` to get the method of the HTTP Request. The APIKIT router will forward the same event that the HTTP Listener will receive, so it will contain [`HTTPRequestAttributes`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.7/http-documentation#HttpRequestAttributes). For more info you can refer this section [HTTP Request Example](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.7/http-listener-ref#http-request-example)